# Can't add additional verification documents to Stripe Connect bank account to enable payouts

Tags: javascript, typescript, stripe-payments

**Question** - What fields do I use to create the correct token to update my Stripe bank account to enable payouts?

I'm trying to enable my Stripe bank account payouts - after using this test routing and accounting number ([test number link](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#trigger-bank-account-ownership-verification)) to trigger a bank account ownership verification status, which disabled payouts.

> routing number: 110000000 , account number: 000999999991

I'm trying to enable the payouts by adding an additional document for the error I receive when I created the account when I used these test numbers.

Error Currently Due:

> documents.bank_account_ownership_verification.files

Attempt 1: I tried updating the account using these [fields](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/update#update_account-documents-bank_account_ownership_verification) but failed

```js
account = {
  documents: {
    bank_account_ownership_verification: {
      files: this.file.value
    }
  }
};
```

I'm getting a Stripe error saying:

> Unrecognized token creation parameter parameter: documents is not a recognized parameter. This may cause issues with your integration in the future.

Attempt 2: Then I tried updating the account with these fields below and failed again to see any payout status change.

```js
account = {
  individual: {
    verification: {
      additional_document: {
        front: this.file.value,
        back: this.file2.value
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I'm getting a Stripe error saying:

> Error updating account. You cannot change `individual[verification][additional_document][front]` via API if an account is verified. Please contact us via ht

FYI - I can generate the account token from both attempts but both fail to update the account with Stripe to enable the payouts

Here is the code to generate the account token which then gets passed to my server where the Stripe API is called to update the account:

```js
// attempt 1
let account = {
  tos_shown_and_accepted: true,
  documents: {
    bank_account_ownership_verification: {
      files: this.file.value
    }
  }
};
// attempt 2
let account = {
  tos_shown_and_accepted: true,
  individual: {
    verification: {
      additional_document: {
        front: this.file1.value,
          back: this.file2.value
        }
      }
   }
};

from(this.stripe.createToken('account', account)).pipe(take(1)).subscribe((result: any) => {

  if (result.error) {
    this.alertService.danger(result.error.message);
  } else {

    this.accountService.updateStripeAccount(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'), result.token.id).subscribe(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/account/banks/accounts']);
      this.alertService.info("Account updated successfully");
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    }).add(() => {
      this.loadingAccount = false;
    });

  }
});
```

Comment: You're looking at the wrong documentation, here's the documentation for `createToken` in the JS library documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=account The documentation you were looking at was for the server side.

Comment: Yes and no! Try clicking on the data - account data link and see where it takes you!!

Comment: This also seems like a possible bug to me - the bank account ownership verification document you're trying to pass in doesn't fit into any of the categories listed in the documentation as things you shouldn't use with tokens (see https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens). You should write into Stripe's support team (https://support.stripe.com/contact) to confirm and ask if it can be fixed.

Comment: hello everyone, please help me to solve my below question. I also have query about upload bank_account_ownership_verification document  using curl api. i got file id with "account_requirement" purpose but i can't upload as bank_account_ownership_verification. please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is that there's no way for you to do this using Account Tokens.

Currently, Account Tokens don't support the `documents` hash so passing in `documents.bank_account_ownership_verification` won't work. Your only option is to pass in `documents.bank_account_ownership_verification` (see [apiref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/update#update_account-documents-bank_account_ownership_verification)) when you update the Account directly (not through a token).